# How to match everything from a literal to the end of the line in ParseKit?

Tags: objective-c, parsing, tokenize, parsekit

I am trying to develop an [UCI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Chess_Interface) parser in Objective-C using ParseKit, but I need a way to match everything from a literal to the end of the line (possibly minus the trailing whitespace).

For example, the line I want to parse is:

```
@"  id name Protector 1.4.0 Linux   \n"
```

My grammar looks like:

```
@start = sentence+;
sentence = 'id' 'name' name;
name = Any+;
```

and

```
- (void)didMatchName:(PKAssembly *)a
{
  NSLog(@"%@", a);
}
```

obviously prints:

```
[id, name, Protector, 1.4, .0]id/name/Protector/1.4/.0^Linux
[id, name, Protector]id/name/Protector^1.4/.0/Linux
[id, name, Protector, 1.4, .0, Linux]id/name/Protector/1.4/.0/Linux^
[id, name, Protector, 1.4]id/name/Protector/1.4^.0/Linux
```

How can I construct a grammar that tokenizes that string in this way?

```
[id, name, Protector 1.4.0 Linux]id/name/Protector 1.4.0 Linux^
```

Answer (score 1):

Developer of ParseKit here. I think if you instead implement the

```
- (void)didMatchSentence:(PKAssembly *)a
{
  NSLog(@"%@", a);
}
```

Method, you will receive an Assembly with the results you want.